# How to order a related table using list of ids in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

here is example of what I am trying to perform;

```
class GroupA(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=250)

class GroupB(models.Model):
   category = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   group_a = models.ForeignKey(GroupA)
```

I have list of ids; `[1, 2, 3]`. How do I perform an order of `GroupA` through `GroupB` using the list of ids.

Currently, an example of data I am returning is;

```
[
{
"id": 3,
"category": "Category 1",
"group_a": [
   {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "John"
   },
   {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "Doe"
   },
   {
     "id": 3,
     "name": "Jane"
   }
]
}
]
```

What I am trying to archive is order the data of `group_a` using list of ids; `[1, 2, 3]`. So it would return something like this;

```
[
{
"id": 3,
"category": "Category 1",
"group_a": [
   {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "Doe"
   },
   {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "John"
   },
   {
     "id": 3,
     "name": "Jane"
   }
]
}
]
```

//Edit

`Serializer.py`

```
class GroupASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = GroupA
       fields = "__all__"
```

```
class GroupBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group_a = GroupASerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    class Meta:
       model = GroupB
       fields = "__all__"
```

`views.py`

```
class GroupBView(APIView):
    serializer_class = GroupBSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):
        group_trip = GroupB.objects.all()
        serializer = GroupBSerializer(group_trip, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: show your current queryset

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use ModelViewSet

```
class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = GroupB.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupBSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return GroupB.objects.all().order_by('id')
```

I didn't check if it works